# How to assign different Datepicker data to different rows within a for loop in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

There is this projects i am on currently. Under date column i pass start and end date and store it in db along with the progress i.e dev, cr fix,etc. What i am trying to do is make a page where the story listed below the user name has its own progress date picker for example:
if i have to assign mark on his story aggregator a progress. Then i will select start and end date and along with the progress and then click submit. I want this to be updated with its specific color in the check datepicker. The check datepicker is only for displaying the progress of the user under the current story. Every user and each of its story can have different progress.

What i did for the same is took the start and end date for the story, its id and its progress and stored it in the db. Then i passed the developer name, id, start and end date and progress from controller to the script of the datepicker using json. The problem is that every datepicker is showing the combined progress of all stories and users. Please help me out for the same. I am providing my HTML, js code and the views for the same.

[This is my project's page image for the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scDlf.png)

This is my HTML and Javascript CODE:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var nDates = {};
      var data  = JSON.parse('{{ d1|escapejs }}');
      var stat = JSON.parse('{{ d2|escapejs }}');
      var jid = JSON.parse('{{ d3|escapejs }}');
      var arr1=[];
      var arr2=[];
      var arr3=[];
      var j_id=[];
      var dev_name=[]
      // alert(data);
      for(i in data){
        for(j in data[i]){
          for(k in data[i][j]){
            if(data[i][j].hasOwnProperty(k)){
                arr1.push(k);
                arr2.push(data[i][j][k]);
                dev_name.push(i);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(dev_name)
      for(i in stat){
        for(j in stat[i]){
          arr3.push(stat[i][j]);
        }
      }

      for(i in jid){
        for(j in jid[i]){
          j_id.push(jid[i][j]);
        }
      }
      console.log(j_id)

      for(var i =0 ;i<arr1.length;i++){
          var day = 1000*60*60*24;
          date1 = new Date(arr1[i]);
          date2 = new Date(arr2[i]);
          var diff = (date2.getTime()- date1.getTime())/day;
          for(var r=0;r<=diff; r++)
          {
             var xx = date1.getTime()+day*r;
             var yy = new Date(xx);
             z=(yy.getFullYear()+"/"+(yy.getMonth()+1)+"/"+yy.getDate());
             if(arr3[i]=='Dev'){
               nDates[new Date(z)] = 1;
             }
             if(arr3[i]=='CR Fix'){
               nDates[new Date(z)] = 2;
             }
             if(arr3[i]=='QA Support'){
               nDates[new Date(z)] = 3;
             }
             if(arr3[i]=='Release Support'){
               nDates[new Date(z)] = 4;
             }
          }
      }


      $('.datepicker1').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          minDate: new Date({{a}},{{b}}-1,{{c}}),
          maxDate: new Date({{d}},{{e}}-1,{{f}}),
          beforeShowDay: function (date) {
              var dev1 = nDates[date];
              var color="";
              if (dev1) {
                  if(dev1==1)
                    color='dev';
                  if(dev1==2)
                    color='cr';
                  if(dev1==3)
                    color='qa';
                  if(dev1==4)
                    color='rel';
                  return [true, color, 'Tooltip text'];
              }
              else {
                  return [false, '', ''];
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

```html
 <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table" id="tab2">
                  <thead class=" text-primary">
                    <!-- <th>Check</th> -->
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Jira ID</th>
                    <th>Overall Status</th>
                    <th>Estimate</th>
                    <th>Actual</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Progress</th>
                    <th>Check</th>
                    <!-- <th>Check</th> -->
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for i in data %}
                    <tr>
                      <td><b>{{ i.name }}</b></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>
                          <div class='box green'></div>-- Dev<br>
                          <div class='box red'></div>-- CR Fix<br>
                          <div class='box black'></div>-- QA Support<br>
                          <div class='box purple'></div>-- Release Support<br>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% for j in list1 %}
                      {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                        {% for k in j %}
                    <form method="GET" id="se">
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ k.0 }}</td>
                      <td>{{ k.1 }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <select class="chosen" name="sel">
                          <option>{{ k.3 }}</option>
                          <option>Live</option>
                          <option>In Progress</option>
                          <option>HTML Done</option>
                          <option>PHP Done</option>
                          <option>API Done</option>
                          <option>QA</option>
                          <option>Pending Development</option>
                          <option>Blocked</option>
                          <option>BLocked on API</option>
                          <option>Blocked on HTML</option>
                          <option>Blocked on Mock</option>
                          <option>Blocked on Spec</option>
                          <option>Not Needed</option>
                          <option>Next Sprint</option>
                          <option>Duplicate</option>
                          <option>CR</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="jid" value="{{ k.1 }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="{{ i.name }}">
                        <input type="button" name="as" value="Assign">
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ k.2 }}</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="startdate" placeholder="Start Date" class="datepicker">
                          <input type="text" name="enddate" placeholder="End Date" class="datepicker"></td>
                      <td>
                        <select class="chosen" name="prg">
                          <option>Dev</option>
                          <option>CR Fix</option>
                          <option>QA Support</option>
                          <option>Release Support</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="j1" value="{{ k.1 }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="{{ i.name }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Check Status" class="datepicker1"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </form>
                        {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my views for the same:

```
def qaprg(request):
id1 = request.session['id']
data = register.objects.filter(roles='dev')
list1=[]
j=0
p = product.objects.get(id=id1)
x = p.sprint_start_date
y = p.sprint_dev_end_date
x=str(x)
a,b,c = x.split('-')
y=str(y)
d,e,f = y.split('-')
a=int(a)
b=int(b)
c=int(c)
d=int(d)
e=int(e)
f=int(f)

list2={}
# m=0
for i1 in data:
    st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i1.name)
    n=0
    list2[i1.name]={}
    for j1 in st1:
        if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j1.jira,dname=i1.name).exists()==True:
            p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j1.jira,dname=i1.name)
            for k1 in p1:
                list2[i1.name][n]={}
                list2[i1.name][n][str(k1.sdate)]=str(k1.edate)
                n+=1
    # m+=1
jd1=json.dumps(list2)

list3={}
m=0
for i2 in data:
    st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i2.name)
    n=0
    list3[m]={}
    for j2 in st1:
        if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name).exists()==True:
            p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name)
            for k2 in p1:
                list3[m][n]=k2.status
                n+=1
    m+=1
jd2=json.dumps(list3)

list4={}
m=0
for i2 in data:
    st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i2.name)
    n=0
    list4[m]={}
    for j2 in st1:
        if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name).exists()==True:
            p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name)
            for k2 in p1:
                list4[m][n]=k2.jd
                n+=1
    m+=1
jd3=json.dumps(list4)


for i in data:
    list1.append([])
    k=0
    st = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i.name)
    for r in st:
        list1[j].append([])
        list1[j][k].append(r.story_name)
        list1[j][k].append(r.jira)
        if r.dev_java==i.name:
            list1[j][k].append(r.javas)
            list1[j][k].append(r.jstat)
        elif r.dev_php==i.name:
            list1[j][k].append(r.phps)
            list1[j][k].append(r.pstat)
        elif r.dev_html==i.name:
            list1[j][k].append(r.htmls)
            list1[j][k].append(r.hstat)
        elif r.dev_qa==i.name:
            list1[j][k].append(r.qas)
            list1[j][k].append(r.qstat)
        k+=1
    j+=1

if request.method=='GET':
    if 'as' in request.GET:
        s = request.GET.get('sel')
        j = request.GET.get('jid')
        n1 = request.GET.get('name1')
        p = story.objects.get(sprint_id=id1,jira = j)
        if p.dev_java == n1:
            p.jstat = s
        elif p.dev_php == n1:
            p.pstat = s
        elif p.dev_html == n1:
            p.hstat = s
        elif p.dev_qa == n1:
            p.qstat = s
        p.save()
        return redirect('qaprg')

    if 'startdate' in request.GET:
        stdate = request.GET.get('startdate')
        endate = request.GET.get('enddate')
        prog = request.GET.get('prg')
        j = request.GET.get('j1')
        n2 = request.GET.get('name2')
        day = np.busday_count(stdate,endate)
        st = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=n2,jira=j) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=n2,jira=j) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=n2,jira=j) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=n2,jira=j)
        z = prg(s_id=id1,jd=j,sdate=stdate,edate=endate,days=day,status=prog,dname=n2)
        z.save()

        list2={}
        for i1 in data:
            st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i1.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i1.name)
            n=0
            list2[i1.name]={}
            for j1 in st1:
                if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j1.jira,dname=i1.name).exists()==True:
                    p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j1.jira,dname=i1.name)
                    for k1 in p1:
                        list2[i1.name][n]={}
                        list2[i1.name][n][str(k1.sdate)]=str(k1.edate)
                        n+=1

        jd1=json.dumps(list2)

        list3={}
        m=0
        for i2 in data:
            st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i2.name)
            n=0
            list3[m]={}
            for j2 in st1:
                if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name).exists()==True:
                    p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name)
                    for k2 in p1:
                        list3[m][n]=k2.status
                        n+=1
            m+=1
        jd2=json.dumps(list3)

        list4={}
        m=0
        for i2 in data:
            st1 = story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_java=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_php=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_html=i2.name) | story.objects.filter(sprint_id=id1,dev_qa=i2.name)
            n=0
            list4[m]={}
            for j2 in st1:
                if prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name).exists()==True:
                    p1 = prg.objects.filter(s_id=id1,jd=j2.jira,dname=i2.name)
                    for k2 in p1:
                        list4[m][n]=k2.jd
                        n+=1
            m+=1
        jd3=json.dumps(list4)

        return redirect('qaprg')

return(render(request,'qaprg.html/',{'data':data,'list1':list1,'p':p,'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d,'e':e,'f':f,'d1':jd1,'d2':jd2,'d3':jd3}))
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet you made to be a [mcve] - I.e. replace template with pure HTML

Comment: what is the problem with this one? this one is better for understanding my page

Comment: The snippet is not runnable. It is full of Template

Comment: that is why provided the image for the same

Comment: Sigh... You have a problem with jQuery datepicker NOT with Django or view or whatever. Post a [mcve] of the jQuery and the RENDERED HTML so we can play with it. Remove the DJANGO tags since your code renders as you want, right?

Comment: the data in the html is linked to database that is why on making it minimal will not make it work

Comment: Never mind. I hope you will get help. I will not eyeball-debug your code or write my own snippet to see why your datepickers do not work the way you want

Comment: In any case, this just is not how you write code. What's with all the single-letter variable names? And so many loops and if blocks. It's unreadable.

Comment: i am new to it, it will come with time